# How to read from a process that hasn't closed?

Tags: c#, .net, process, networkstream

I'm making a simple program in C# that allows a client to connect to a server and run MS DOS commands on that server.

The program worked well, later on I decided I wanted to cmd.exe process to run whilst the client was connected to the server, this is where I'm stuck at.  I wanted this so that I could
run commands like *CD* and change the working directory, previously this would've had no effect because the cmd.exe process was closed after the command was run.

It appears that I can only read from the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` streams if the process has exited, is there any workaround for this?

Here's some of my code used in the program :

**Creates and returns cmd.exe process: **

```
private Process createDOS()
{
    try
    {
        // Create a ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd","");

        // Set up the values
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        // Create a cmd.exe process
        Process process = new Process();

        // Apply the start info and run
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();  

        return process;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Method that formats the response into a string :**

```
private string findResponse(StreamReader err,StreamReader outp)
{
    string output = outp.ReadToEnd();
    string error = err.ReadToEnd();

    string ret = "";

    // Add the output to the return field if the process actually output data
    if (output.Length > 0)
    {
        ret = "OUTPUT : " + output;
    }

    // Then attempt to add data from the error stream
    if (error.Length > 0)
    {
        // If output was read, add a newline character separating the two fields
        if (ret.Length > 0) ret = ret + Environment.NewLine;
        ret = ret + "ERROR : " + error;
    }

    // If there's no output, that means there's no error, which means the execution was silently succesful
    if (ret.Length <= 0)
    {
        ret = "Command execution succesful!";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**Server listener block :**

```
private void run()
{
    while (true)
    {

        Stream stream = null;
        StreamReader sr = null;
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        Process proc = null;

        try
        {
            socket = server.AcceptSocket();

            stream = new NetworkStream(socket);

            sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

            String mode = sr.ReadLine();

            sw.WriteLine("Serverside link connected");
            sw.Flush();

            // Create cmd process in WINPROCESS mode

            if (mode == "WINPROCESS")
            {
                proc = createDOS();
            }

            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (mode == "WINPROCESS")
                {
                    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);
                    proc.StandardInput.Flush();

                    // Response
                    sw.WriteLine(findResponse(proc.StandardError, proc.StandardOutput));
                    sw.Flush();

                }
                else
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exeDOS(line));
                    sw.Flush();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Silence
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null) socket.Close();
            if (stream != null) stream.Close();
            if (sw != null) sw.Close();
            if (sr != null) sr.Close();
            if (proc != null) proc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a handler to the [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx#) and [ErrorDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) events:

```
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += 
        new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);

    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += 
        new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);

    if (process.Start())
    {
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```